# Why i am getting a warning about of string type if i am passing a string?

Tags: vue.js

i want to pass a String to my child component like this, but previously i want to print it

this is my parent component

```
    {{left.leftA}} // here show me 8
        <CustomCard
          :left="left.leftA"
export default {
    name: 'Parent',
    data() {},
    setup() {
    onMounted(async () => {
        const answer = await getData(name)
        left.value = answer.response //{leftA:'A', leftB:'B'...}
      })
```

and in my child component i have this declaration

```
export default {
    name: 'CustomCard',
    props: {
    left: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
```

i am getting this warning:

```
  [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "left". Expected String with 
value "undefined", got Undefined
```

Does it have something to do with how I am loading the data? is it ok to use onMounted?

Comment: `try: :left="\`${left.leftA}\`"`

Comment: It seems that `left.leftA` is not containing any value!

Comment: Make sure it holds some value and that value is of type `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the initial value for value is null. So, on initial render it throws the warning, but upon another render it has the correct prop type (a string) and renders correctly.

You have 3 options. Allow '' as an option on the prop or don’t render the component until you have the correct data or make use of computed Property.

**Option-1**

```
{{left.leftA}} // here show me 8
    <CustomCard
      :left="left.leftA ? left.leftA : ''"
```

**Option-2**

```
{{left.leftA}} // here show me 8
    <CustomCard v-if="loaded"
      :left="left.leftA"

and in onMounted(}

  onMounted(async () => {
        const answer = await getData(name)
        left.value = answer.response //{leftA:'A', leftB:'B'...}
        // Set the loaded flag as true here. Also make sure its set as false inside the setup()
      })
```

Option-3

```
{{left.leftA}} // here show me 8
    <CustomCard
      :left="sendVal"



In computed....

computed: {
  sendVal() {
   if(left && left.left1) return left.left1;
   return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: i am using onmounted to get datas before to render is ok?

Comment: inside parent or child?

Comment: By Child, I mean `CustomCard`

Comment: i edited my question, Does it have something to do with how I am loading the data? is it ok to use onMounted?

Comment: Yes, if you see you are hitting an api and then setting the data. By by the time the mounted gets executed, your template wud have been already loaded. Thats the reason its throwing that error. So In this case you can have a flag called `loaded` and then once you set the value of `left.left1` inside mounted, you set the `loaded` flag to be true and use the same in the template like 
` <CustomCard v-if="loaded"` which I have already explained in `Option-2`

Comment: can you improve your answer with loaded flag please

Comment: Updated it. you can check it now